# Comparing Date Ranges in Google Analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics, jqplot, google-analytics-api

I'm currently working on a live dashboard of data from Google Analytics using JqPlot
I can return the current days traffic by hour which is great, but what I also want to do is to create a graph that has today's traffic and the same day last week's data.

Basically I want to return the same data as I can when I compare date ranges in GA.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks
Adi

Answer (score 0):

Create two variables as startDate and endDate

Get current days traffic AS below

set startDate and endDate as today date (i.e startDate=2014-10-01,endDate=2014-10-01)

then use below query

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga:YOUR PROFILE ID
  &start-date=startDate 
  &end-date=endDate 
  &metrics=ga:sessions
  &dimensions=ga:hour
```

And get last week's same day data

set startDate and endDate as last week same day date (i.e startDate=2014-90-26,endDate=2014-09-26)

and then use below

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga:YOUR PROFILE ID
  &start-date=startDate 
  &end-date=endDate 
  &metrics=ga:sessions
  &dimensions=ga:hour
```

Comment: Hi 
I'm using the following to create the query
public function setHourlyData(&$analytics, $profileId) {
   $dimension = 'ga:hour';
   return $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profileId, 'today', 'today', 'ga:visits', array('dimensions' => $dimension));}

Can you explain in this format please?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this now

var line1 = [[00,4],[01,3],[02,3],[03,1],[04,1],[05,1],[06,8],[07,11],[08,41],[09,54],[10,71],[11,72],[12,0],[13,0],[14,0],[15,0],[16,0],[17,0],[18,0],[19,0],[20,0],[21,0],[22,0],[23,0]];

var line2 = [[00,7],[01,3],[02,3],[03,1],[04,0],[05,3],[06,11],[07,21],[08,40],[09,54],[10,69],[11,91],[12,76],[13,45],[14,63],[15,52],[16,38],[17,33],[18,26],[19,28],[20,26],[21,31],[22,9],[23,9]];

```
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [line1, line2],

        {
        axes:   {xaxis: {pad: 0},
                    yaxis: {pad: 0, max: 100}
                }
        }
    );
```

Thanks