# Google Analytics Embed Api - Compare To Past

Tags: date, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I can't see a way in the embed api to implement a chart comparison between two date ranges. There doesn't seem to be anything in the options object to achieve this.

I've found two posts:

[Comparing Date Ranges in Google Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176351/comparing-date-ranges-in-google-analytics-api)

Which suggests querying the first date range, then the second. I'm assuming the idea is to superimpose one ato the other, but am not sure how to achieve this.

[Using Google Analytics APIs to create charts comparing data across date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719286/using-google-analytics-apis-to-create-charts-comparing-data-across-date-ranges)

This one suggests OP found a solution with the same approach, but no tips on how to implement it. If anyone can point me at existing sample code, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with **Embed API *Third Party Visualizations***:

[image]

You can recreate the demo from documentation: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/

Comment: Thanks for this. I think that will do the job nicely.